# I want to load variables in subshell.sh but I don't want to source it

Tags: linux, bash, yocto

I only need the `greentea` variable in `subshell.sh` but I don't want it to run `echo abcd`

```
cat subshell.sh 
#!/bin/bash
export greentea="super"
echo abcd
```

**Update**:

The real problem:

Building yocto, the config is complicated and runs by a script, but it didn't provide with available source script, it just runs everything.

I only need its configs and run `bitbake -n core-image-minimal`

**Update**:

Someone else provided the `subshell.sh`, I can't change it but I need to use it, and he/she will often update/change the `subshell.sh`

Comment: `source <(grep -v 'echo abcd' subshell.sh); declare -p greentea` or `echo "${greentea@A}"`

Comment: the actual `subshell.sh` is a big and complicated script, I seem can't do it this way.

Comment: Then explain what ithe real goal is, I gave you a solution for your actual question did i not?

Comment: If you don't like Jetchisel's approach, then maybe it's the perfect time to refactor that script-monster into smaller units, that you can call separately?

Comment: The real script is complicated and operates with other variables, can't just take it simply processed by 1 line command.

Comment: You could use multiple commands. Or what if you alias bitbake first, so your script won't execute it, and then unalias it? like `alias bitbake=true; source ./subshell.sh; unalias bitbake`
Your script will try to run the bitbake commands, but it won't do anything, just return immediately.

Comment: `source <(grep '^export greentea=' subshell.sh)` just takes that particular variable definition. Can you explain why it does not work ?

Comment: the variable need to run in run time to get the result.

Comment: @skandigraun, this looks like a good solution.

Comment: @skandigraun, the console closed directly, and the `subshell.sh` seems too complicated.

Comment: You have to either extrapolate one of the suggested solutions and adapt them to your script until it starts working, or you gotta ask the author of the script to add an option to the script that does what you want it to do.